# "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a rails app. I am using dynamodb for the database tables. I get the error

> The provided key element does not match the schema

**In my helper/controller:**

```
session[:id] = @record.id
```

**In my view:**

`<% record_id = TableName.find(session[:id]) %>`

I printed the `session[:id]` and checked, it has the correct id of the particular record. Also checked the db. The record matches with my desired one. It works fine in rails console.

But, when I run the application, I get the above error.

Kindly help.

Comment: You are missing what is in your view

Comment: Does it work fine in the Rails console both when you pass the id as a number and when you pass it as a string? Maybe just calling `to_i` on your id can solve your issue?

Comment: That did not solve the problem. I have added more clarity to the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get that error from DynamoDB it is because the key you are providing doesn't match the type of the key in your table. Either your table has a key that is defined as a String and you're passing in a Number; or vice versa - the table's key is a Number and you're passing it in as a String.